# Python replacing more than string

Tags: str-replace

For example if there is string = "wbwwbw" and I want to replace "w" to "bw" and "b" to "w" so that if I print the string out it can be "bwwbwbwwbw"?

Comment: Am I understanding you right that you would like to replace two different patterns basically at the same time? I would say in your case the easiest way would be to first change all "b" to "x" then, all "w" to "bw" and then all "x" to "w". Using a temporary variable is often a trick to "switch things". Also please take the [tour] and visit the [help]. Which programming language are you working with? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can replace the "b" with an "x", something that is not present in your string and that you can definitely find again at a later point.

After that you replace the "w" with "bw".

The last stage is to replace all "x" with "w".

This way you are using a temporary storage for the replacing and can use the built-in functions of your language of choice for the replacing.

Just make sure that your temporary pattern is definitely not present in your original string. Otherwise you get a different result than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating the string char by char:

```
str = 'wbwwbw'
str2 = ''

for c in str:
    if c == 'w':
      str2 += 'bw'
    elif c == 'b':
      str2 += 'w'

assert str2 == 'bwwbwbwwbw'
```